# Command Line Calculator

Tags: java

I am trying to make a command line calculator using Java, I have come up with the code below it works without the `if-else` ladder,but I can't make it work with `if-else`, during debugging I tried printing the "z" which is indeed add when the arguments are passed as `java name 1 2 add`, But I can't seem to trigger the `id (z == "add")`, please suggest what I am missing.

```
public class commandlinecal {
        public static void main(String arg[])
        {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(arg[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(arg[1]);
                String z = arg[2];
                if (z == "add")
                {
                        add(x,y);
                }
                else if (z == "sub")
                {
                        sub(x,y);
                }
                else if (z=="mul")
                {
                        mul(x,y);
                }
                else if(z=="div")
                {
                        div(x,y);
                }
        }

          public static void add(int x,int y)
          {
                int result = x + y;
                System.out.println("The sum is" + " "+result);

          }
          public static void sub (int x,int y)
          {
                  int result = x-y;
                  System.out.println("The sub is"+" "+result);

          }
          public static void mul (int x,int y)
          {
                  int result = x * y;
                  System.out.println("The multiplication is"+" "+result );
          }
          public static void div (int x,int y)
          {
                  float result = x / y;
                  System.out.println("The division is"+" "+result);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if (z.equals("add")) { ... }` instead.